# How to use bulk collect in a dynamic query?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-queries

My piece of code currently fetches data into a object using the following code:

```
SELECT ORDR_LIST(ORDER_NUMBER,ORDER_TYPE,ORDER_DATE,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_NAME) BULK COLLECT INTO P_RESULTSET
            FROM
              (SELECT ORDER_NUMBER,
                        ORDER_TYPE,
                        ORDER_DATE,
                        CLIENT_ID,
                        CLIENT_NAME
                      FROM
                        (SELECT ORDER_NUMBER,
                          ORDER_TYPE,
                          TO_CHAR(ORDER_CREATED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS am') AS ORDER_DATE,
                          CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME
                          ||' '
                          ||CUSTOMER_SURNAME AS C_NAME,
                          CLIENT_ID,
                          CLIENT_NAME
                        FROM CONNECT_CUSTOMER_TRANS
                        WHERE ORDER_TYPE              =P_ORDER_TYPE
                        AND lower(CUSTOMER_SURNAME)   =lower(P_LAST_NAME)
                        AND lower(CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME)=lower(P_FIRST_NAME)
                        AND lower(CLIENT_ID)          =lower(P_CLIENT_ID)
                        AND ORDER_CREATED_DATE BETWEEN P_FROM_DT AND P_TO_DT
  )
 WHERE C_NAME=I.CUS_NAME);
```

Now i have dynamically generated the select statement into a variable var1 . However I am unable to implement it in the dynamic part.

The code should look like :

```
SELECT ORDR_LIST(ORDER_NUMBER,ORDER_TYPE,ORDER_DATE,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_NAME) BULK COLLECT INTO P_RESULTSET
            FROM var1
```

which will be run by execute immediate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will be something like:

```
execute immediate 
'SELECT ORDR_LIST(ORDER_NUMBER,ORDER_TYPE,ORDER_DATE,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_NAME) 
from ('||var1||')' BULK COLLECT INTO P_RESULTSET;
```